# Positioning of Divs - centered + fixed insues

Tags: html, css

I have a div "general" which is centered on the page. Inside I have a fixed div at the top. Outside of that div "general" have the "footer" that is fixed to the bottom of the page. So far so good .. the problem is that the div "content" must be centered vertically and horizontally within that div "general ".... Can someone give me some tips there positioning?

```
<body>
        <div id="mb_background" class="mb_background">
            <img class="mb_bgimage" src="images/default.jpg" alt="Background"/>
            <div class="mb_loading"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="mb_geral">

            <div id="mb_topo">

                <div id="mb_logo">
                    <a href=""><img src="images/logo_dentro.png" alt="Logotipo"/></a>
                </div>

                <div id="mb_menu">

                </div>

                <br clear="all"/>

            </div>

            <div id="mb_conteudo">

                alguma coisa aqui

            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="mb_footer">
            <a class="mb_left" href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"/></a>
            <a class="mb_left" href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png"/></a>
            <a class="mb_left" href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/news.png"/></a>

        </div>      
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
margin:0 auto;
```

in your css will centre the content div horizontally, to center it vertically, youd need

```
top:50%;
margin-top:-[insert half of the content div's height here];
```